# Error connecting git on terminal

Tags: git, terminal

I'm trying to connect my git account using Terminal but every time I use the command:

```
xcrun git config --global user.name 'username'
```

I get an error stating:

> error: could not write config file /Users/admin/.gitconfig: Permission denied

How do I work through this issue?

Comment: Did you try to run with `sudo` ?

Comment: No. What's sudo? @pseudoAJ

Comment: `sudo` basically lets you do things from the terminal with root permissions --  which you do need in order to do what you're doing. Plop `sudo` in front of that whole command chain, enter your password when it asks, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I should be more cautious here; if you're trying to do something from the command line and it tells you 'Permission denied', the solution is often to enter `sudo` in front of the rest of the command -- but ONLY do this if you know what the command you've entered does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rename your .gitconfig file to "somethingelse.gitconfig" git will create a new .gitconfig file and the error should be gone

If not, try run with sudo

```
sudo xcrun git config --global user.name 'username'
```

Comment: how do i rename my .gitconfig file to "somethingelse.gitconfig"?

Comment: navigate to the path where the error has specified and rename that file. So go to `/Users/admin/.gitconfig` and rename it there. If you cant get to the file, in finder click on the toolbar, then click Go>Go To Folder and paste the path I wrote above